# Use the mean value theorem to prove that

Tags: calculus

Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove that

$$\frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{(2x-1)}{\sqrt3} < \arcsin x < \frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{(2x-1)}{2\sqrt{1-x^2}} \qquad \text{for} \ \frac{1}{2}\leq x< 1.$$

How can I prove the inequality above?
Give me a clue or a full proof.

Comment: Context? Source? Effort on part of OP?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** apply the mean value theorem to $f(x)=\arcsin x$ on $[1/2,x]$. Recall $f'(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and observe this is increasing on $[0,1)$.